# How to make a table full of images stick to screen width in html

Tags: html, css

I am using HTML to create a web page that has a table of 6 images that has 2 rows and 3 columns, this is my code:

```
<table style="width:100%">
    <tr>
        <td><img src="House1.jpg"></td>
        <td><img src="House2.jpg"></td>
        <td><img src="House3.jpg"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><img src="House4.jpg"></td>
        <td><img src="House5.jpg"></td>
        <td><img src="House6.jpg"></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

But when I load up the web page it overflows to the right and I have to scroll right to see all the images. Is there any way to fix that?

Comment: What's your goal with these tables? Why you don't use a flex-layout where you have more control over the sizes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

do some changes

1. use `display: block;`
2. And make  `width: 100%;` as well as  `height: 100%;`

example :

```
<img style="display:block;" width="100%" height="100%" src="House1.jpg" />
```

Hope this will help!

Comment: Perfect! That really helped!